# From (being) high-pitched to low-pitched

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

**Context**: On Tiktok, there is a filter with which your face turns blue and deforms several times. This filter is accompanied by music which becomes lower-pitched music every time the face changes.
Is the following description grammatically correct?
*it is the filter accompanied by music from high-pitched to low-pitched.* 
It sounds like terrible English to my ears.

Comment: The grammar is correct, and it sounds fine to my American English ears.

Comment: @TinfoilHat what if I added *which is* between *music* and *from*, would it still bear the same sense?

Comment: @TinfoilHat - Of course, you have a tin ear!

Comment: Without specific details as to *why* it sounds terrible, and what aspect you think needs to be changed, this is just asking for proofreading. (What was wrong with the second sentence in your question?) It's also not clear what details are important to add. For instance, the accepted answer doesn't mention that it starts off as *high-pitched* in any way—which could be a key detail to include. (Even though you didn't mention its absence in comments.)

Comment: @JasonBassford what do you think of the sentence *it is a filter accompanied by music WHICH IS from high-pitched to low-pitched*? Is it still to turn the adjective phrase into an adjective clause by inserting *which is*?

Comment: @JasonBassford brilliant. Thanks bassford :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

"Each time the filter changes the appearance of your face, there is accompanying music that decreases in pitch."

Another possibility, which is a little more evocative, could be, "Each time the filter changes the appearance of your face, there is accompanying music that winds down in pitch."

This would indicate that every time you hear the music, it starts high and ends lower.

Both make sense to me as a native English speaker.

Here's what might be a useful distinction for you. If, instead, you mean that the first time you hear the music, it's pitched in one range or key, the next time you hear it, it's pitched in a lower range or key, and so on, you might say:

"Each time the filter changes the appearance of your face, the pitch of the accompanying music is lower."

Comment: Got it. By the way, can we use the phrase *from x to x* without a noun when both x's are adjectives? For instance: There are a lot of girls in the room, *from the most beautiful to the ugliest.*

Comment: @FadiiSheikh, would you accept the answer to your original question?

Comment: I do. I am just still bothered by this *from* matter. So, it is okay to use *from adjective + adjective* without a noun or *being*, right?

Comment: @FadiiSheikh, responding to your comment: Yes, you can sometimes use adjectives without nouns. You can say "the pitch moves from high to low", but musical pitch is often described in relative terms (when is a pitch considered "high"?), so this doesn't seem to do the job you were looking for. You might say "from higher to lower". The sentence from your comment  sounds a little off because of the superlatives -- "beautiful to ugly" might work better (although a few extra words would help the sentence sound better). An example that works well: _a lot of dog breeds, ranging from large to small_.